# Cannot call Count(predicate) on list

Tags: vb.net, ienumerable

The following code produces results that are confusing. Note I am coming from C# background and know very little VB.

```
Module Module1
Sub Main()
    Dim list As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
    Dim result As Integer

    result = list.Count() '1
    result = list.Count(Function(p) True) '2
    result = CType(list, IEnumerable(Of String)).Count(Function(p) True) '3
End Sub
End Module
```

The confusing bits:

1. There is a property named Count and an extension method with the same name. By calling Count() I expect the extension method to be called, but the property is accessed. Why and how to invoke a method?
2. I expected extension method call, but compilation fails with BC32016 (as if property was accessed instead of method). Why is that?
3. This works as expected.

Comment: It just has to do with VB.Net syntax, inherited from VB6, where `result = list.Count', or `result = list.Count()' would both access a property. When both exist in VB.Net, the property is always selected (as long as the method has a parameterless overload). c# is more explicit about this and `result = list.Count;` or `result = list.Count();` will access the property or method, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a limit of VB since doing this doesn't compile. A is already a property, can't have a method with the same name.

```
Class Test

    Public Property A As Integer

    Public Function A(ByVal b As String) As Integer
        Return 0
    End Function

End Class
```

You also have other options.

```
    Enumerable.Count(list, Function(p) True)
    list.AsEnumerable.Count(Function(p) True)
```

Comment: `Count` is a read-only property of `List<T>`, and `int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)` is an extension method of `Enumerable`. Trying to define the property and method in a single class is not applicable.

Comment: However, the "other options" listed are fine